# Cannot read property 'add' of undefined error when updating variables which control html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use numbers as element ids, represented in js by i, and once the start button is pressed, it should hide the title screen, update i, and then removes the hide class (which hides an element) from the new i element (question 1) and the menu bar element. Question 1 and the menu bar should be left onscreen. However, the menu bar loads, but the question doesn't, and the error pops up.

> Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

```js
// variables
var i = 0;
var id = document.getElementById(i.toString());
var next = document.getElementById("next");

// hiding menu and other screens
menuBar.classList.add('hide');
next.classList.add('hide');

document.getElementById("1").setAttribute("class", "hide");
document.getElementById("2").setAttribute("class", "hide");
document.getElementById("3").setAttribute("class", "hide");
document.getElementById("4").setAttribute("class", "hide");
document.getElementById("5").setAttribute("class", "hide");

// show the next screen when the next button is pressed
function nextScreen() {
  id.classList.add('hide');
  if (i == 0) {
    menuBar.classList.remove('hide');
  }
  i ++;
  
  next.classlist.add('hide');
  id.classList.remove('hide');
}

start.onclick = nextScreen;
next.onclick = nextScreen;
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <!-- title screen -->
      <div id='0' class='title'>
        <h1>
          Welcome to<br>the<br><strong>IMPOSSIBLE QUIZ</strong>
        </h1>
        <button id='start' class='green button'>
          START
        </button>
      </div>
      
      <!-- question 1 -->
      <div id='1' class='question'>
        <span class='questionIndicator'>
          Question 1
        </span>
        <br>
        <h2>
          What is after
        </h2>
        <button id='secretAnswer' class='secret'>
          ...?
        </button>
        <button id='q1WrongAnswer' class='answer button'>
          this?
        </button>
        <button id='q1WrongAnswer' class='answer button'>
          the answer
        </button>
        <button id='q1WrongAnswer' class='answer button'>
          no idea
        </button>
      </div>

      <!-- menu bar below questions -->
      <div id="menuBar" class="menuBar">
        <button id='mainMenu' class='small red button'>
          MAIN MENU
        </button>
        <button id='next' class='small next button'>
          NEXT QUESTION
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You are not defining what `menuBar` is anywhere. You need to specify it as *HTML Element*.

Comment: To clarify, I only added the part of the code necessary to show where the errors occur. I didn't want to waste anyone's time so I didn't add the full HTML, CSS and JavaScript. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: id cannot start with digit, try adding something in front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elements with an ID of 2-5 don't exist yet, so you cannot call `setAttribute()` on them.

Also, `next.classlist.add('hide')` should be `next.classList.add('hide')` (camelCase)

Comment: Thanks, I am very disappointed in myself. However, now, it removes 'hide' from the same screen (title screen) after it hides it and updates 'i'. I am not sure if the issue is with updating 'i' or another error with the variables or code. Any thoughts?